# Why state flow calls callectLatest multiple times?

Tags: android, kotlin

So,  I would like to use StateFlow instead of LiveData, but I can not figure out what's the problem with my logic.

I have a flow, which has a default null value. When I open a dialog which contains a some datas, after that I select one data, I emit the new value to the flow.

In the first time, after the dialog closed, collectLatest called, and I get the null value (init), after the emit, I get the new value, it is good. But If I open the dialog again, and select value, and close the dialog, the collectLatest fun called 3-times, and I again open the dialog... and collectLatest called 4 times and so on.

So this is very bad behavior, and I'm sure , I did something wrong, but I don't see the bug.

In the liveData the expected behavior is after the dialog close, that the observer fun is called just once. I would like to achive this.

I also checked, that I emit the new value only once, so there is no reason why collectLatest fire multiple times.

ViewModel:

```
    private val _previousManufacture = MutableStateFlow<PreviousManufactureView?>(null)
    val previousManufacture = _previousManufacture.asStateFlow()

private suspend fun setPreviousManufactureByMachineId(machineId: String) {
        val result = stateReportRepository.getPreviousManufactureByMachineId(machineId)

        if (result is Result.Success) {
            _previousManufacture.emit(result.data)
        } else {
            _previousManufacture.emit(null)
        }
    }
```

Fragment:

```
            lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
                viewModel.previousManufacture.collectLatest {
                    var d = it
                }
            }
```

[Update]
Fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.vm = viewModel

        initFlows()
}

 private fun initFlows() {
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            viewModel.openStateOfWorkflowBrowser.collectLatest {
                openStateOfWorkflowSelectionDialog()
            }
        }
...
}
```

Comment: Can you show more of your Fragment code? I have a feeling you're calling `launchWhenCreated` every time you open or dismiss the dialog, instead of a single time in `onViewCreated()`, so you're adding more and more duplicate, parallel collectors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited my question, and added more codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I missed this before in my comment, but I think the problem is that you are calling `launchWhenCreated` in the `lifecycleScope` of the Fragment, not in its `viewLifecycle.lifecycleScope`. So if the Fragment is reused (like after a dialog fragment has a appeared), the old collector is not cancelled and a new one is added, because the lifecycle of the Fragment has not ended, only the lifecycle of its previous view. You should almost always use `viewLifecycle.lifecycleScope` when you are using coroutines in a Fragment.

Comment: Lot of thanks, it seems I'm already tired, because I remember that being mentioned somewhere, but I was inattentive